# Script runs fine, but when run by cron can't do the Dropbox upload

Tags: python, cron

I'm running a python script on my raspberry pi, which makes some modifications in a SQL database, writes a log, and uploads everything to dropbox.
When I'm launching it using command line everything works fine.

UPDATE: When I'm launching it using cron, everything works, except for the Dropbox upload. No error messages in the log. The file simply doesn't appear in my dropbox.

Here is the code I am using:

```
from subprocess import call
data = "/home/pi/scripts/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh upload /home/pi/scripts/database.db /"
call ([data], shell=True)
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Not sure, so posting as comment instead of answer, but I think cron runs with your home directory as its working directory, so your script tries to create `/home/pi/test.txt` and does not have write permissions there.

Comment: The test script worked after adding an absolute path, yet my full script is not working even with absolute paths. The issue seems to be somewhere else..

Comment: I would suggest to create a shell script say "myjob.sh". In the script, change directory to your project home. then execute the python script. e.g.

    `cd  /home/pi/scripts`

    `python test.py`

Then run this shell script "myjob.sh" using cron.

Answer (score 0):

*It works from an interactive terminal and not from cron* is almost always an evidence of an PATH or environment problem. When you use an interactive session, the profile and eventually basrc files are used to set a number of environment variables including PATH. None of them are used from cron. So good practices are:

- always use absolute path in scripts that can be launched from cron
- explicitely set PYTHON environment variables in your crontab, or use a minimal shell to set them first and then start python